# Changing Dates in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to replace worksheet automatically. Currently I have multiple worksheets with the title "JAN 18", "FEB 18", "MAR 18", etc. I have a userform that initiates prior to the macro being ran. I am able to enter a new year (ie: 2019), however the code continues to display "18" for my form year. It is like the entry into the userform is not working. The script I am using utilizes a case statement to select the desired files with a previous year and replace it with the current year.

```
Sub NewFiscalYear()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim PrevYear As Integer
Dim FormYear As Integer

FormYear = Format(Date, "yy")
PrevYear = FormYear - 1

'Disabling Display Alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Changing FY Date on Forms
     If FormMonth = "AUG" Then

        For Each ws In Worksheets
            Select Case ws.Name
                Case "JAN " & PrevYear, "FEB " & PrevYear, "MAR " & PrevYear, "APR " & PrevYear, _
                "MAY " & PrevYear, "JUN " & PrevYear, "JUL " & PrevYear, "AUG " & PrevYear, _
                "SEP " & PrevYear, "OCT " & PrevYear, "NOV " & PrevYear, "DEC " & PrevYear
                    ws.Name = "ws.name " & FormYear
            End Select
        Next
    End If
```

I am working on a large report that gathers information from multiple other workbooks. My userform includes a date to enter (FormYear) and a month to choose from via a combo box (FormMonth). Once these are selected, the macro is ran. I have the report working great, however have been running into hiccups with the new FY.

*****My goal is to have users run the report on the first month of the new fiscal year, hopefully without them noticing anything has changed (with the exception of it looking like a brand new worksheet). The tabs indicate the current month that was selected along with the fiscal year that was selected in the userform prior to running the macro. Once the tabs are identified with the new year, I am going to go through and reset all of the forms with blank data. I hope this made things a bit more clear!*****

Any tips or tricks would be mostly appreciated!

Comment: In you case statement you are looking for JAN on the worksheet name but your worksheet names are JAN 18 so you never actual hit any of the case statements.  use the left function to extract the 3 characters.

Comment: What is `FormMonth`?

Comment: Presumably, FormMonth is a field on a Userform?

Comment: @Comintern thanks for the help! I'm tweaking with things now. FormMonth is a combox box option that appears on the userform when the workbook is initiated. I have this workbook pulling from a variety of sources and the FormMonth (JAN, FEB, MAR etc) are used mostly as strings to reference text to open and reference other workbooks. I run a report once a month and this simply references the month I will be working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your renaming line is all wrong:

```
ws.Name = "ws.name " & FormYear
```

This would attempt to change "JAN 18" to "ws.name 19" because you've wrapped the object in quotes.

Even if you got the quotes right:

```
    ws.Name = ws.name & " " & FormYear
```

It would change "JAN 18" to "JAN 18 19"

---

Try:

```
ws.Name = Replace(ws.Name, PrevYear, FormYear)
```

---

**EDIT**

Also, I think your PrevYear/FormYear might be incorrect.

I'd go with:

```
PrevYear = Format(Date, "yy") ' so this is the current year value
FormYear = PrevYear + 1       ' this becomes next year value
```

Comment: that makes sense. Things tend to run together after a while!

Answer (score 2):

`FormYear = Format(Date, "yy")` will return `18` until the clock rolls around on Jan 1, 2019.

If you need to get `19`, *now*, you need either:

`FormYear = CInt(Format(Date, "yy")) + 1`

or

`FormYear = CInt(Format(DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Date),"yy"))`

---

After further clarification, this should do what you're after:

```
Sub NewFiscalYear()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim PrevYear As Integer
  Dim FormYear As String

  FormYear = CInt(Format(Date, "yy"))
  PrevYear = CStr(FormYear - 1)
```

Note the explicit conversion from strings to integers and back. VBA will do this for you, but this way you (and everyone else) knows it's intentional

```
'remove these lines until everything works fine
  'Disabling Display Alerts
'  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Declare a constant here so you know why this "magic value" is there. *You* know that's the start of the fiscal year, but 5 years from now, when that changes, someone else may not know why this doesn't work anymore and not realize that the FY start changed.

```
  Const FISCAL_YEAR_START_MONTH as String = "AUG"
  'Changing FY Date on Forms
  If FormMonth = FISCAL_YEAR_START_MONTH Then

    For Each ws In Worksheets
      Select Case ws.Name
        Case "JAN " & PrevYear, "FEB " & PrevYear, "MAR " & PrevYear, "APR " & PrevYear, _
             "MAY " & PrevYear, "JUN " & PrevYear, "JUL " & PrevYear, "AUG " & PrevYear, _
             "SEP " & PrevYear, "OCT " & PrevYear, "NOV " & PrevYear, "DEC " & PrevYear
```

Once you've found a worksheet whose naming pattern matches what you're looking for, extract the first 3 characters (the month name) and append the new year to the end of it.

```
          ws.Name = Left(ws.Name, 3) & " " & CStr(FormYear)
      End Select
    Next
  End If

'disabled them earlier, make sure we reenable them now
'doesn't hurt to enable them if they weren't disabled earlier
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Would this mean that come Jan 1, 2019 I would need to modify the code to remain on 2019 so it doesn't pull 2020?

Comment: I think it would rename the first sheet to `ws.name 19` and throw an error for the next (same name)

Comment: It would depend on how often you run this... Based on `If FormMonth = "AUG" Then`, it looks like you only want to rename the sheets if this is run in August - you'd need logic to prevent execution in other months. You could also check to see if the sheet names match "this" year's date - if so, leave them alone, if not change them.

Comment: @CLR - it _works_ fine, it just doesn't _do_ anything once it's found a matching sheet name.

Comment: @DerekHarden - maybe it would help everyone if you [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52838506/edit) your OP to describe in more detail how you envision this working.

Comment: @FreeMan: There is a statement `ws.Name = "ws.name " & FormYear` that would be executed (for every sheet that matches the `Select`)

Comment: Looks like I will keep digging. My end goal is to write a macro that will basically "reset" the workbook for a new FY. Previous FY information will be saved. The goal is to have the user select the year and month they are running the report (ie: AUG) as normal without having them have to go back and make a bunch of manual changes. Really, the goal is for users to not even notice that changes have taken place (except for when they see the new sheet names)

Comment: @FunThomas- Yeah, I see that now. That's formatted so oddly I totally missed it. The actual assignment looks just like the rest of the `Select`

Comment: @DerekHarden - give this a shot now.

Comment: @FreeMan - Works like a gem! Thank you for your and everyone else's help! Still new to the whole VBA thing. The formatting and knowledge is coming, just a little learning curve!

Comment: Glad to hear that, @DerekHarden. An upvote and clicking the check mark are a good way to let everyone know that this has been resolved